# Fix size tag "li" and for bold font size decrease

Tags: html, css, size, html-lists

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Ridermansb/5jJg3/2/) site, please note that in `a:hover` put the source as bold.
The problem is that the font size decreases and eventually I read it also decreases.

There are two errors in the HTML you would like your help:

1. The source should not decrease when ally is in bold.
   In the event `a:hover` can not change the size of the tag `li`.
2. The tag `li` must have fixed size, and not size depending on content. How can I fix the size of the `li`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent the boxes from jumping by

1. floating the `li`s
2. adding a `width` to the `li`s
3. adding left and right `padding` to the `li`s
4. taking the `hover` off the `a` and adding it to the `li`s

--

```
ul#menu li {
 float:left; 
 width:120px; 
 background-color: #676767; 
 text-align:center; 
 padding:20px 20px; 
 margin:0 .25em;
}

ul#menu li a {
 color: #FFFFFF; 
 text-decoration: none;
} 

ul#menu li:hover {
 font-weight: bold; 
 background-color: #868686; 
 color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/5jJg3/10/

**Important**:

1. the bolder text still jumps, but the boxes do not
2. you will only be able to click on the text ** however you can make the entire `li` clickable with js, if you like.

Comment: thanks for fixing the formatting @clairesuzy.  it wouldn't do it for me no matter what I did!

Comment: is there any way to make the whole read is clickable without using js?
For example in adding the tag "a" to fill the entire read, so it would all be clickable

Comment: note that from a menu and another one there esac blank. How can I remove it?
I checked the Debug Chrome and it is not an edge, margin or padding.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I understood your question correctly, but can't you put

```
ul#menu li
{
   width:200px; //change this amount...
}
```

Comment: That's right.

Now, only missing the first question.
Note that when I move the mouse on the link, the font is bold, but it decreases in size ... ally it should not?

Comment: It may be the way the font does the bold. If I remove all the font declarations and just have font-family: Sans-Serif; it gets bigger when it's hovered on...

Comment: It definitely is the way Calibri bold is rendered. Remove Calibri from the font-family list and you get Trebuchet MS and see the increase in tracking of the bold variant.

Comment: Thanks.. note that from a menu and another one there esac blank. How can I remove it?
I checked the Debug Chrome and it is not an edge, margin or padding.

Answer (score 1):

I took the liberty to touch your css code to achieve the desired result. It would be:

```
ul#menu li
{
    background-color: #676767;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
ul#menu li a
{
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    line-height: 45px;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100px;
}
ul#menu li a:hover
{
   letter-spacing: 1px;
   font-weight: bold;
   background-color: #868686;
   color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

What I did was:

- Remove padding from `li` and `a` elements (it should be 0)
- Set the `a` element to `display:block` with fixed width and height
- Set `letter-spacing` of `a` and `a:hover` to 1px so they keep the same space between characters
- Keep the text in the center with `line-height` and `text-align:center`

The problem was that padding was pushing the box borders when the element changed its size.